# What is the closest syscall to `perf_event_open` on Windows

Tags: windows, winapi, profiling, system-calls, perf

What syscalls should I use on Windows to obtain CPU event counters?

Perfect for me would be something close to Linux's `perf_event_open` syscall.

For example: How would I count L2-cache-misses and branch-misses of some random function `f()` inside huge application via syscall?

Comment: That's not standardized by POSIX!  It's Linux specific, as documented in the man page:  https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/perf_event_open.2.html#STANDARDS .  IDK how other OSes support tools like Intel's VTune, whether it has to provide its own kernel drivers to virtualize the PMU counters across context switches the way Linux does, or what.  I suspect some features of the perf API (PAPI) might be unique to Linux.

Comment: Or wait, is PAPI a specific library, not another name for the API `perf_event_open` provides?  It seems so: https://icl.utk.edu/papi/  Oops, I've mis-tagged some past questions.

Comment: [Recording Hardware Performance (PMU) Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/wpt/recording-pmu-events) might be what you're looking for. I don't know whether this can be set up using the [ETW API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/etw/about-event-tracing).

Comment: See https://github.com/Siemens-Healthineers/ETWAnalyzer/blob/main/ETWAnalyzer/Documentation/DumpPMCCommand.md how you can get the data with ETW and how to analyzer it. I have also created custom wprp profiles at https://github.com/Alois-xx/etwcontroller.

Comment: Windows Performance Counters provide a way to collect performance data. You can access these counters programmatically using the PerformanceCounter class in .NET or through the Windows Performance Monitor tool. However, they might not offer the same level of detail as perf_event_open.

Example in .NET:

using System.Diagnostics;

PerformanceCounter cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total");
float cpuUsage = cpuCounter.NextValue();
This code gives overall CPU usage, but specific counters like L2-cache misses might not be available.